# Need to restart the app to get changes displayed?

Tags: android

I am working  on first project Notes app. I  am facing an issue I have successfully created database and I am able to save and retrieve data from database the issue I am facing is once I save a note I need to restart the app for it to display. If I can get any help that would be really nice

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private List<Note> noteList=new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NotesAdaptor notesAdaptor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //function to get all list
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=db.getReadableDatabase();
        noteList.addAll(db.getAllNotes(sqLiteDatabase));
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        notesAdaptor=new NotesAdaptor(this,noteList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdaptor);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new NotesLongClickListener(this, recyclerView, new NotesLongClickListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionDialog(position);
            }
        }));
        FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showNoteDialog(false,null,-1);

            }
        });

    }


    private void deleteNote(int position){

        db.deleteNote(noteList.get(position));
        notesAdaptor.notifyItemRemoved(position);

    }


    private void showActionDialog(final int postion){
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose option");
        builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("Database Operations","Note deleted");
                    deleteNote(postion);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void addNote(String s){
        DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database=db.getWritableDatabase();
        db.createNote(s,database);
        db.close();
        notesAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Note Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void showNoteDialog(final boolean update, final Note note, final int position){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_notes,null);
        builder.setView(view);


        final EditText inputNote=view.findViewById(R.id.add_note_dailog);
        TextView dailogTitle =view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_itle);
        dailogTitle.setText(!update?"New Note":"Update Note");

        if(update &&  note!=null){
            inputNote.setText(note.getNote());
        }
        builder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(update ? "update" : "save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog  alertDialog=builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputNote.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter note!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
                if (update && note != null) {
                    // update note by it's id
                   // update(inputNote.getText().toString(), position);
                } else {
                    // create new note
                    addNote(inputNote.getText().toString());
                }
            }

        });



    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Need to restart the app to get changes displayed?

You are facing this issue because when you performing the action of item adding and removing from your database, at the same time not  performing any action in your list  that's why you need to restart the app

There are **Two issue** in your code

> **Issue 1** : in your `deleteNote()` method you are not removing item from your list

```
private void deleteNote(int position){

    // remove item from your list than use notesAdaptor.notifyItemRemoved(position);    
    noteList.remove(s); 

    db.deleteNote(noteList.get(position));
    notesAdaptor.notifyItemRemoved(position);

}
```

> **Issue 2** : in your `addNote()` method you are not adding item in  your list

```
private void addNote(String s){
    DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database=db.getWritableDatabase();
    db.createNote(s,database);
    db.close();

    // add item in your list than use notesAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    noteList.add(s);
    notesAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();


    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Note Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked did some modification though thanks